# How to make the map reduce more than 100 records in mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, monodevelop

How to make the map reduce more than 100 records in mongoid

```
lists = UserStayedTime.where(:starttime.gte => u, :rl_mac_id=>{"$in" => ["00:18:0A:21:D4:58"]}).or(:endtime.lt => (u + 1.year))
```

this giving morethan 1000 records..

```
 map = %q{function() {  emit(this.rl_mac_id, {vid : this._id})  } }
 reduce = %Q{ function(key, values) { var result = {"vds2" : []} values.forEach(function(ust){   result.vds2.push(ust.vid)   }) return result;     } }
```

so

```
 lists.map_reduce(map,reduce).out(inline: true).to_a
```

its giving only 120 records only

Anyone please help me....